# Creating multiple identical CCSprites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Is there a clean and efficient way to create an arbitrary number of identical CCSprites?

I really just need a tag to reference them for later removal.

For example in my game I am displaying the number of lives in a HUD:

```
- (void)displayOneLife
{
    CGPoint positionOne = ccp(90, 450);

    CCSprite *life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];
    [life1 setPosition:positionOne];
    [life1 setScale:0.5f];
    [self addChild:life1 z:5 tag:1];
}

- (void)displayTwoLives
{
    CGPoint positionOne = ccp(90, 450);
    CGPoint positionTwo = ccp(105, 450);

    CCSprite *life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];
    CCSprite *life2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];

    [life1 setScale:0.5f];
    [life2 setScale:0.5f];

    [life1 setPosition:positionOne];
    [life2 setPosition:positionTwo];

    [self addChild:life1 z:5 tag:1];
    [self addChild:life2 z:5 tag:2];
}

- (void)displayThreeLives
{
    CGPoint positionOne = ccp(90, 450);
    CGPoint positionTwo = ccp(105, 450);
    CGPoint positionThree = ccp(120, 450);

    CCSprite *life1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];
    CCSprite *life2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];
    CCSprite *life3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];

    [life1 setPosition:positionOne];
    [life2 setPosition:positionTwo];
    [life3 setPosition:positionThree];

    [life1 setScale:0.5f];
    [life2 setScale:0.5f];
    [life3 setScale:0.5f];

    [self addChild:life1 z:5 tag:1];
    [self addChild:life2 z:5 tag:2];
    [self addChild:life3 z:5 tag:3];
}
```

Comment: I would use CCSpriteBatchNode if all the sprites will have the same texture. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927516/most-efficient-way-to-deal-with-multiple-ccsprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CCTexture2D` using your image and then init all of the sprites using that texture.
This way you only load the image once.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Also , you can add them dynamically. Like this:

```
- (void)displayLifes:(int) nrOfLifes
{
    CGPoint position = ccp(90, 450);
    CCTexture2D *texture = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"life.png"]]autorelease];

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= nrOfLifes ; i++)
    {
         CCSprite *life = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
         [life setPosition:position];
         [life setScale:0.5f];
         [self addChild:life z:5 tag:i];

         position.x += 15;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: sprite with texture is a bad constructor. it will caouse problems, for example, when you will pack your images in the atlases using zwo[tex or texture packer. so, you should accept YvesLeBorg's answer as this answer will potentially cause problems later.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the CCSprite constructor looks up in cocos' texture cache, and if the cache already contains the texture, il reuses its texture. So you could simplify further by removing the *texture (which i believe is leaked here), and just use do this:

```
- (void)displayLifes:(int) nrOfLifes
{
    CGPoint position = ccp(90, 450);    

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= nrOfLifes ; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *life = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"life.png"];
        [life setPosition:position];
        [life setScale:0.5f];
        [self addChild:life z:5 tag:i];
         position.x += 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed , the texture doesn't get duplicated , didn't know that. Anyway , it's better to avoid the cache search so I still think it's optimum to provide the texture. As for the leak , I got used to ARC lately , thanks for the heads up. Cheers!

Comment: actually, there will be no leak as he create autoreleased texture.

Comment: True in general, but this creator is not autorelease. Typically in cocos, an [CCSomething somethingWith:parameters] is auto release. However an [[CCSomething alloc] initWithParameters:parameters] is not.

Comment: really?)))) dude, do you think i don't know it?) take a look into his example. he simply send autorelease to this texture after creation

Comment: ah. sorry M, i did not see it first time around. Actually, i assume little about who knows what, and you should not assume that you are the only reader of this forum either :), although you know lots. notin personal meant here